# motion of rectangle by keyboard

Tags: java

I made the following code to move a rectangle using arrowkeys of keyboard. The "keyPressed" function does not seem to be working properly.Infact, i don't think it is even getting called when a key is pressed bcz when i tried to print some text when a key is pressed, it was not getting printed.All i see in the output window is a stationary rectangle fixed at the top left corner of the window.Here is my code....pls help me...i need it desperately

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JFrame window=new JFrame();
    window.setSize(600,400);
    window.setTitle("window");
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    drawingComponent DC=new drawingComponent();
    window.add(DC);
}
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class drawingComponent extends JComponent implements ActionListener,KeyListener
{
Timer t=new Timer(2000,this);//moving after 5 milliseconds
static int x=0;
static int y=0;
private static int velx=0;
private static int vely=0;

public drawingComponent()
{
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    System.out.println("tr1");
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect1=new Rectangle(x,y,50,30);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(rect1);
    System.out.println("tr2");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //inbuilt fncn f actionListener(interface) which needs to be created
{
    x+=velx;                //changing values
    y+=vely;
    System.out.println("tr3");
    repaint();          //inbuilt fncn to repeat the paintComponent method
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    int code=e.getKeyCode();
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    { velx=0; vely=-1;repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        { velx=0; vely=1; repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {vely=0; velx=-1; repaint(); }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {vely=0; velx=1; repaint();}

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of `KeyListener`s...

While you have set the component focusable, you've not requested that the component be focused.

You could try calling `requestFocusInWindow`, but he this raises the question of when to call it.

You could call it within the constructor, but because the component doesn't belong to a valid visible component yet, the call may fail. You could override the components `addNotify` method and add the call to it, after you call `super.addNotify`, but the `requestFocusInWindow` method doesn't gurentee that focus will be given the component

Instead, you could simply avoid all this hassle and use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which will give you control over the level of focus require for key events to be triggered

As a side note, you should call `setVisible` on your frame after you've set up the UI completely

Comment: KeyListener will continue to give y issues and often when you lest expect it to